# How Could I Display Key Expiration With KeyAuth.com

Tags: c#

So I'm using KeyAuth.com for a project I'm working on and I've run into an issue, I'd like to display when the key expires [image: here] here but it's not working.

I put:

```
Private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    KeyExpirationButton.Text = "Key Expiration: " + Login.KeyAuthApp.user_data.Expires;
}
```

so it would display expiration but it's not working.

Comment: What _exactly_ do you mean by "not working"? And what's the value of `Login.KeyAuthApp.user_data.Expires` when you run this code?

Comment: well its not displaying the expiration date. i used a label for that key expiration so maybe thats why